# Will Kafka Reuse an old disk for writes after a new disk has been added?

Tags: apache-kafka, disk

I have a question about using multiple disks per Kafka broker.
Assume that a Kafka broker has 3 disks associated with it.

i) Disk-1 was full in 5 days

ii) Disk-2 is nearing 40 % usage in the next 3 days.

Now if the `log.retention.hours = 168` (7 days) has completed, then let’s say the data in Disk-1 was deleted, so Disk-1 is free again and Disk-2 is 40% used

Now will Kafka reuse Disk-1 for new writes again, or will it only write to new disks i.e Disk-2 , Disk-3 so on?

Basically, my question is, will Kafka again write to an older disk, if there is enough free space in the older disk due to message deletion after max retention days in Kafka ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a partition is created, each broker that is a replica will pick a select a log directory to put data for that partition. On a broker, data for a specific partition is only stored in that selected log directory.

Log directories are specified in the broker configuration via the `log.dirs` setting.

If you have multiple log directories, when creating a partition, the log directory with the least amount of partitions is picked.

When producing messages to a partition, the data goes into the log directory where that partition is.

In short the answer to your specific question is "it depends" but hopefully I've described the process clearly enough for you to figure out the answer for your exact situation.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. If Disk-1 has lesser number of partitions than Disk-2 after the deletion of messages in Disk-1 due to log retention days, then data will be again written to Disk-1. This is what I have inferred from your answer. Am I right ?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply and your help.